# How to lock your cursor in Unity while using UFPS and Inventory Pro?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am messing around with UFPS and Inventory Pro which are both assets that claim to be compatible after looking through the tutorials that both companies posted I realized that both of them are outdated and some of what they say is there is not. In the tutorial, they say you can click a  checkbox to lock your cursor but in the new Inventory Pro, that checkbox isn't present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answering your question, you can set the Cursor.lockState in a script if you add a public boolean.  Look at the Unity Manual.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html

Just add a public boolean and if it's checked, lock it in `Start()` and maybe test for the press of the escape key which will "unlock" the Cursor.  If it's not checked, well, you won't lock the cursor in `Start()`